# Are there any benefits to using the NextJS API?

Tags: express, next.js

I'm about to build out my API for my service and I'm wondering if there are any benefits to building it out using the NextJS API integration. It seems a little quirky for my own preferences and the resources aren't as exhaustive as they are for my ideal solution: expressJS. That said I'm aware there are some integrations that would allow me to use express inside the NextJS API but that seems excessive compared to standing up a separate repo for my express API.

So, I'm curious are there any under-the-hood benefits or perks to leveraging the NextJS API within the same repository as the rest of my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your application. Truth is probably a good portion of websites and projects just need a simple request server-side to retrieve data. Having Next.js API helps manages your serverless functions. You could easily do it with AWS's Lambdas and API gateway but the management of many serverless functions can get messy. You can also use CLI tools but Next.js with Now and Netlify can automatically do all this during build/CI/CD.

Under the hood is an AWS Lambda, so the usual can be an issue...cold starts, computing resources. But great for things like accessing private APIs, lower on-demand costs, and development as functions. If its heavy computational data, I would avoid using serverless and just spin up your own separate service. But the plumbing is all the same as an Express or KOA server, its just on-demand and a tool to manage. I just see it as a really easy and simple tool to do a little bit of backend work without maintaining infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for the insights!